# ¿Por qué la función me devuelve la función nested completa y no el valor return que le pido?

Tags: javascript

Intentando hacer un challengue básico de dado un numero, hacer una función que devuelva el numero "factorizado". Es decir, si pongo en la función `factorialize(5)` me debería devolver 120 (5*4*3*2*1). Si pongo `factorialize(10)` me debería devolver 3628800

He hecho esto

```js
function factorialize(num) {
  function factorizar(){
    let multiplicado = function(){
   for (let i = num; i >= num; i--){
     num*=num-i
      }
   return num
 }
 return multiplicado
  }
  return factorizar()
}

factorialize(5);
```

Sé que el loop no está correcto, pero recién estaba haciéndolo y antes de ponerlo correctamente quería ver cuanto daba "num" tal como está ahora mismo la función.

Pues bien si ejecuto la función en vez de devolverme "num" me devuelve todo esto:

```js
ƒ (){
       for (let i = num; i >= num; i--){
          num*=num-i }
         return num
         }
```

¿Por qué? Me he asegurado de poner el "return num" fuera del for loop

Comment: Con `return multiplicado` estás devolviendo una función, no la ejecución de esa función.

Comment: @Kiko_L entiendo, entonces mejor eliminar la variable multiplicado y simplemente poner función multiplicado, no? No se porque lo compliqué así

Answer (score 0):

Respetanto al maximo tu codigo, una forma de hacerlo seria asi:

```
function factorialize(num) {

  function factorizar(num){

    let multiplicado = (function(num){
        let total = 1 // Cuenta

      for (let i = num; i > 0; i--){

           total *= i

        }

      return total
    })(num) // Autoinvocamos la función

    return multiplicado
  }

  return factorizar(num)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que añades más complicación de la necesaria.

1. la función `factorizar` tal y como la estás usando no tiene mucho sentido porque simplemente estás devolviendo la función multiplicado.
2. La propia función multiplicado tampoco tiene sentido. Sería más lógico hacerlo en una única función. Puede estar bien como ejercicio para aprender sobre el uso de funciones dentro de funciones pero si no yo la quitaría.
3. Además el `for` está mal:

   `for (let i = num; i >= num; i--){
       num*=num-i
   }`

Si empiezas en `i=num=5` y estás haciendo que a tu variable `i` se le reste 1 en cada iteración, la condición de salida no puede ser que `i` sea mayor o igual que `num`. Debería ser `i > 0`. Además, no tienes que restar `i` a `num` ya que simplemente quieres multiplicar el num que tienes en cada iteración por la i de dicha iteración `num*=i;`. Y por último, ya que nada más empezar num es 5 en este caso, tendrás que inicializar la `i` como `i=num-1`

Dejo un ejemplo con la función multiplicado incluida:

```js
function factorialize(num) {
    let multiplicado = function(){              
        for (let i = num-1; i > 0; i--){
              num*=i; 
           }
            return num;
      }
      return multiplicado();
}

console.log(factorialize(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues más simple que esto no se me ocurre nada, porque me parece que has complicado, de más, el asunto. Hay que restarle a num antes de meterlo en el búcle, de lo contrario se multiplica por si mismo la primera vez. Después iteras y, al final hacer un return de num, pasado como parámetro a la función factorialize(). He puesto la variable numeroprompt para que puedas meter un número desde un prompt creado en la misma variable. Con poner num en lugar de numeroprompt la función queda como la tuya.

```js
var numeroprompt=prompt("introduce tu número")
function factorialize(num) {       
   for (let i = numeroprompt-1; i > 0; i--){
     num=num*i;
      }
   return num
 }
 console.log(factorialize(5));
```

Es decir, debería ser esto:

```js
function factorialize(num) {       
   for (let i = num-1; i > 0; i--){
     num=num*i;
      }
   return num
 }
 console.log(factorialize(5));
```

Cualquier duda pregunta :D